# Extjs not able to upload file second time when it was already uploaded

Tags: javascript, extjs, file-upload, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a strange behavior of extjs file upload.

The file upload defined as:

```
 items: [{
                    xtype: 'filefield',
                    itemId: 'uploadandsign',
                    buttonText: NG.getLabel('browse'),
                    buttonOnly: true,
                    hideLabel: true,
                    width: 100
                }]
```

If the file uploading is success I show successful label on the screen with remove "X" button:

```
onOpenFileBrowserChange: function (filefield, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
            var me = this,             
            form = filefield.up('form').getForm(),
            infoBox = invoiceorigin.down('#fileuploadinfoplaceholder'),
            fileDescription,
            secondfilefield,
            customerFileName = newValue.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, ''),
            draft = me.getDraft(),
            isSigned = true,
            files = draft.files();

        if (filefield.itemId === 'uploadandsign') {
            isSigned = false;
            secondfilefield = invoiceorigin.down('#uploadnosign');
            fileDescription = 'File system, Unsigned';
        }           
        secondfilefield.disable();

        if (form.isValid()) {
            form.submit({
                url: NG.getLatestApiPath('WebInvoice', 'UploadInvoiceFile'),
                waitMsg: NG.getLabel('webinvoiceInvoiceOriginUploadingFile'),
                success: function (fp, o) {
                    if (o.result.success) {

                        var file = o.result.file;

                        files.add({
                            fileName: file.fileName,
                            createDate: file.createDate,
                            isAttachment: false,
                            isSigned: isSigned,
                            fileOrigin: fileDescription,
                            customerFileName: customerFileName,
                            invoiceFileOrigin: 'Local'
                        });

                        filefield.disable();
                        infoBox.removeAll();
                        infoBox.add(Ext.create('NG.view.webinvoice.InformationBox', {
                            data: {
                                closable: true,
                                icon: true,
                                iconCls: 'n-pdf-icon',
                                content: '<div class="n-text-overflow" style="width:145px;">' + fileDescription + '<br/>' + customerFileName + '</div>'
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                    else {                            
                    }
                },
                failure: function (form, action) {
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    },
```

Then if I remove the file from #infobox, the reset() function called:

```
onRemoveFileClick: function (view) {
            var me = this,
            invoiceorigin = view.up('invoiceorigin'),
            uploadNoSignBtn = invoiceorigin.down('#uploadnosign'),
            uploadAndSignBtn = invoiceorigin.down('#uploadandsign'),
            infoBox = invoiceorigin.down('#fileuploadinfoplaceholder'),
            draft = me.getDraft(),
            files = draft.files(),
            pagemanager = view.up('webinvoicepagemanager'),
            invoiceFilePlace = files.findExact('isAttachment', false);

        me.deleteFileConfirmReject(
            NG.getLabel('webinvoiceInvoiceOriginDeleteInvoiceFileTitle'),
            NG.getLabel('webinvoiceInvoiceOriginDeleteInvoiceFileMsg'),
            function (buttonId, text, opt) {
                if (buttonId == 'yes') {
                    infoBox.removeAll();
                    if (invoiceFilePlace > -1) {
                        files.removeAt(invoiceFilePlace);
                    }

                    me.fillInvoiceOriginStep(pagemanager);

                    uploadNoSignBtn.reset();
                    uploadAndSignBtn.reset();
                    uploadNoSignBtn.enable();
                    uploadAndSignBtn.enable();
                }
            });
    }
```

After this action if I will choose the same file.... nothing happens with page... no any  change event fired on the page.. However if I choose different file the behavior is OK.
In the ExtJS documentation said that the reset() function have to clear previous files uploads... however it does not helps.

Is any body met such file upload ExtJS behaivour and could help with this issue?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

What I tried and worked quite good was to get the file from the form with a typical JS **document.getElementsByName('[name you gave]');** and it got perfectly the file uploaded without mattering in wich execution you are in.

Hope it helps.